# Using google API's from Appengine (OAuth)

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth, storage, prediction

I want to use [Google Prediction](http://code.google.com/apis/predict/) from a Python [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/) Application. Google Prediction requires you to store your "prediction models" in [Google Storage for Developers](http://code.google.com/apis/storage/), in effect meaning that to use GP you must use GSD. Unfortunately, both GP and GSD seem to require OAuth 2.0 .

This Oauth stuff is really getting in the way though! All the examples I find seem to deal with the case of wanting for access a users data/credentials/identity/whatever using Oauth. I have no need for that. I simply want to access a resource (GP and GSD) from my server using http request. Repeat, I just want to use some of their services, I have no need at all to access any other users information!

I can see from my Google API console that I have created both a id and secret for my GAE applications domain. Is it not possible to just use these values to do OAuth authentication to other Google API's? Effectively saying "I am the application at domain xyz, here are my credentials, let me use your API"? It seems kind of ridiculous that Google is currently forcing people to use such a burdensome authentication system for things that they are ***trying to get people to try out***?

I am hoping there is some magical awesome library that will take care of all these OAuth details for me. Short of that, a code example of how to do these things in Python App Engine would be useful. I just want to use the Google Prediction and Google Storage for Developers services from my python GAE app, but I am blocked by the burden of having to configure all of this OAuth stuff. Isn't there some easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Look at the [Google API Python Client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/wiki/OAuth2). You should just be able to put your tokens in and connect. There are some examples on the page that should give you enough information to connect in.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/wiki/SupportedApis although this does support Prediction, it does not appear to support Google Storage for Developers. Is it possible to use this for GSD?

Comment: Yes. They talk about it in the [GSD Authentication page](http://code.google.com/apis/storage/docs/authentication.html). The page also has an example program (in Python) to show how it works.

Answer (score 3):

I'm the Product Manager at Google working on the Prediction API.  The first thing I want to say is thank you for trying out the API and for reaching out to the world about your issues!  We hear you!  We are very aware of the difficulty of using the API in some cases and some of the pain OAuth2.0 can cause for the simple use cases.   In particular I tried to do exactly what you were doing a few weeks ago and was myself rather frustrated!  We're working on it!

OK, so, that's all nice and dandy, but do I have anything helpful for you?  Hopefully I do!  I managed to get my GAE application working with GP -- I shelved the GSD component for the moment as I ran out of time, so hopefully somebody else can lend you some sample code for that (it should involve using boto & OAuth to handle the tricky bits).

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2Credentials
# You can find an example oauth2client in the python prediction sample code

# Replace everything in <>'s
credentials = OAuth2Credentials(
    "<access_token>", #probably empty string
    "<client_id>",
    "<client_secret>",
    "<refresh_token>",
    <Expiry>, # Probably None
    "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
    "<app_useragent>")

http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
service = build("prediction", "v1.3", http=http)
```

You should be able to get the client id an client secret from the API console.  You can use any sample application or demo, e.g. the python sample code, to generate a refresh token.

Best of luck!  Feel free to followup directly with me (zg@google.com) or post to our public discussion list (prediction-api-discuss@googlegroups.com) if you still have any trouble.

Comment: I should note that the sample code I posted really is just for development -- before you go into production it is highly recommended to carefully read the Google OAuth 2.0 documentation and understand the security implications of various ways of implementing the system.